# Getting a “dynamically typesafe view” of a collection through the algorithms of Collections class

Tags: java, generics, collections

I quote from Herbert Schildt book on Java,

> One thing to pay special attention to is the set of checked methods, 
>       such as `checkedCollection( )`, which returns what the API documentation 
>       refers to as a **“dynamically typesafe view”** of a collection. This view 
>       is a reference to the collection that monitors insertions into the 
>       collection for type compatibility at run time. An attempt to insert 
>       an incompatible element will cause a `ClassCastException`. Using such 
>       a view is especially helpful during debugging because it ensures that 
>       the collection always contains valid elements. 
>       Related methods include `checkedSet( )`, `checkedList( )`, `checkedMap( )`, and 
>       so on. They obtain a type-safe view for the indicated collection.

Prior to **Generics**, the code was not type-safe, and its misuse could result in run-time exceptions. Generics prevent this from occurring. In essence, through Generics, what were once run-time errors have become compile-time errors. This is a major-advantage. In the process, they eliminate the need for me to enter casts and to type-check code by hand.

So, why the need to monitors insertions into the collection for type compatibility at run time, when it is clearly achieved at compile time through the use of Generics, and why the need for checked methods?

What does the author mean by the **“dynamically typesafe view”** of a `collection`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because despite you have generics, you can send them on raw methods and still get runtime errors. Here's an example:

```
public void addUnrelatedInfo(List list) {
    list.add(5);
}

//...
List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<>();
stringList.add("hello");
addUnrelatedInfo(stringList);
stringList.add("world");
System.out.println(stringList);
```

And you get this output:

```
[ hello, 5, world ]
```

As you can see, it just happens to use a method that receives a raw interface/collection and your code can be doomed.

The problem is not thinking on you creating such odd methods, but there are some libraries that are Java 1.4 compatibles and their interfaces take as parameter raw types.